# How does this reaction occur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I was doing homework for my chemistry class, and I came across a question asking to complete and balance the following acid-equation:

$$\ce{Cu(OH)2 (s) + HClO4 (aq) -> ?}$$

At first I thought it was an acid-base reaction, but clearly $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ is a precipitate. Thus, it could not be an acid-base reaction, and I was under the impression there was no reaction at all.

However, it turns out that the answer was to the question was (courtesy of the back of the textbook):

$$\ce{Cu(OH)2 (s) + 2 HClO4 (aq) -> Cu(ClO4)2 (aq) + 2 H2O (l)}$$

How is this possible? The answer to the question was exactly the same as an acid-base reaction, despite a precipitate instead of a base in the reactants.

Anyone know why this is the answer, or if it is even correct?

Comment: What makes you think it cannot be an acid-base reaction because one of the reactants is in solid state? $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ is also poorly soluble in water, but I don't think you'd doubt it reacts with $\ce{HCl}$ reagrdless.

Comment: Since its not soluble, how can it produce OH- in a solution?

Comment: Why it should produce $\ce{OH-}$ *in solution*? The reaction takes place at the interface.

Comment: If no $\ce{OH-}$ is produced, how is it a base?

Comment: What is it then, if not a base?

Comment: I was under the impression it was just a normal ionic compound. If it was a base wouldn't it produce $\ce{OH-}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An acid or base can react with a solid. For instance HCl will dissolve $\ce{CaCO3}$ with much fizzing of $\ce{CO2}$ gas.

You also miss the point that $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ has a solubility product. So there is a small amount of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ and $\ce{OH^-}$ in solution.

$\ce{K_{sp} = [Cu^{2+}][OH^-]^2}$

The perchlorate anion is a powerful oxidizing agent, but since $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ is fully oxidized no redox reaction occurs.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. That clears up my confusion a lot, but since $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ is a weak base (I'm assuming it is), shouldn't the neutralization of it with perchloric acid be in the form $\ce{HA+B->A-+HB+}$, rather than forming water?

Comment: @Frank you have essentially the right equation in your question $$\ce{Cu(OH)2 (s) + 2 HClO4 (aq) -> Cu(ClO4)2 (aq) + 2 H2O (l)}$$ The only quibble I'd have is that the $$\ce{Cu(ClO4)2 (aq)}$$ is solvated , so it would be $$\ce{Cu^{2+} + 2ClO4^-}$$ in solution. Also I think the copper ion would coordinated with water molecules rather than the perchlorate anion.